# Using NDepend to find out places where specific objec types are placed in System.Web.Caching.Cache

Tags: c#, ndepend

I'm trying to search a rather large codebase for methods where Large objects are ending up being used in any of the `System.Web.Caching.Cache` methods. These type can sometimes be so big that they end up on the Large Object Heap which in turn is a bad thing.

Basically we have the class `ExternalProject.ReallyBigType` that is being inherited into several different classes.
And we have some different methods,  lets call these `CacheUsingMethods`, that use methods in `System.Web.Caching.Cache` (via other implementations and so on).
I want to find the `CacheUsingMethods` that use objects of type `ExternalProject.ReallyBigType` (or objects that derive from `ExternalProject.ReallyBigType`) and make them end up in any of the methods in `System.Web.Caching.Cache`.

Is there some way to accomplish this using NDepend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
let bigTypes = Application.Types.Where(t => t.DeriveFrom("ExternalProject.ReallyBigType"))
let cacheUsingMethods = Application.Methods.WithNameLike("RegeExToMatchThoseMethods")
from m in cacheUsingMethods.UsingAny(bigTypes)
let bigTypesUsed = bigTypes.UsedBy(m)
select new { m, bigTypesUsed }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response Patrick, it seems however that Dependency Injection is breaking my flow here - i e the Cache parts are being injected into classes that need them. As a bonus the actual `ExternalProject.ReallyBigType` is being transferred via a callback delegate ( `Func<T>`) into the cache method.